# Django - struggling with excessive queries

Tags: python, django

I need to implement a website menu where every root item can have a dropdown with some more items, and I need to do that using some django models and without any third party tools like mptt. So it will be a tag.

So here are the models:

```py
    class Menu(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    
    class MenuElement(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        menu = models.ForeignKey('Menu', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
```

And here is the function that's supposed to do the trick:

```py
    def draw_menu(menu_name):
        menu_elements = MenuElement.objects.filter(menu__name=menu_name).select_related('parent')
        for element in menu_elements:
            if not element.parent:
                element.children_list = element.children.all()
```

And here comes the problem. If I get a list of all children of a menu element, it's super easy to display the thing on the web page. But if I leave it like this, there will be an additional query for every root element (to get the children), so 10 elements = 10 queries. And select related cannot really help in here, at least I don't see how to utilize it. 10 queries for a menu is not an option, even 2 is too much, is it possible to do the whole thing using one? Maybe if I redesign the model somehow?

Comment: What is `if element.parent` doing?

Comment: If element.parent is null, then it's the root element and I need to get all the children of it.

Comment: so if the menu goes three items deep, you don't want to fetch the third level?

Comment: It's two level by design, I needed to clarify that, my bad.
I really need to make it work with one query, and If the tree may have more levels, then it probably needs a recursive function to traverse and get all the elements, I honestly don't see how it can be made with one sql query and without third-party tools .

Answer (score 2):

You can work with [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) here:

```
def draw_menu(menu_name):
    root_items = MenuElement.objects.filter(
        menu__name=menu_name, parent=None
    ).prefetch_related('children')
```

This will load all root elements and all the *direct* children with *one* extra query. So not *per* parent, so the entire task to fetch all root elements and subelements is two queries.

In the template you thus can render it with:

```
{% for item in root_items %}
    {{ item }}
    {% for child in item.children.all %}
        {{ child }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It will not work for a third level though. Although we can do that with:

```
def draw_menu(menu_name):
    root_items = MenuElement.objects.filter(
        menu__name=menu_name, parent=None
    ).prefetch_related('children__children')
```

but then it will not work with a fourth level. But given the menu is (usually) not that deep, that often does not matter much after a few levels. Yes, for each such sub-sub-sub-…-menu, it will indeed need to make extra querie(s), one for each of its parents.

> 10 queries for a menu is not an option, even 2 is too much, is it possible to do the whole thing using one?

Technically *yes*, but that would introduce *data duplication* in the result, which would increase the bandwidth between the database and the Django layer, which can eventually result in a larger problem: the database returning massive amounts of the same text, and thus render the server unresponsive.

Comment: But please add 'all' to {% for child in item.children %} in case someone finds this solution online. Without 'all' it returns a TypeError.

Comment: @Jafes: ah yes, that changed some years ago. Thanks. Updated!